# Unknown is not supported - f1 score

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I want to do f1 score with 32 predicted masks images and 32 true masks images. My data has this features:

```
predicted.shape [32,512,512]         

true.shape [32,512,512]

type_of_target(predicted) Unknown      

type_of_target(true) Unknown

type_of_target(predicted[0]) Continuous-multioutput   

type_of_target(true[0]) Continuous-multioutput
```

When I run this line f1_score(true, predicted, average='macro')
I get this error:

```
f1_score(true, predicted, average='macro')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-75-7198c91642b6>", line 1, in <module>
    f1_score(true, predicted, average='macro')

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_classification.py", line 1099, in f1_score
    zero_division=zero_division)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_classification.py", line 1226, in fbeta_score
    zero_division=zero_division)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_classification.py", line 1484, in precision_recall_fscore_support
    pos_label)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_classification.py", line 1301, in _check_set_wise_labels
    y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_classification.py", line 97, in _check_targets
    raise ValueError("{0} is not supported".format(y_type))

ValueError: unknown is not supported
```

Answer (score 2):

**F1-Score** is the Harmonic Mean of Precision and Recall. Precision and recall are calculated when the predicted values are categorical and not continuous outputs. You need to convert the predictions to categorical (by rounding up or rounding down) then flatten the array since the `f1_score` function only takes 1D-arrays as the input parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I think F1 input should be 1d array (label).
Make sure of that.

Comment: Thanks, you are correct. The input in f1 score has to be 1d array. So I use flatten() and now my predicted and true has this shape (8388608,) but the error "continuous is not supported" happens